# Different token is generated and one of hazelcast server nodes is out

Tags: token, load-balancing, hazelcast, hierarchical-clustering, internal-load-balancer

We are having a strange problem. Any help is appreciated.

Our product is running on 4 different nodes, each has their individual Hazelcast servers. The traffic is controlled by load balancer among them.

Sometimes, Hazelcast cluster works like 2 different clusters(1st-3rd and 2nd-4th) and each cluster generates different tokens. And that is only observed when the webservice requests are coming to the server across the DataPower. There is not any problem with the UI requests sent within the same server.

Do you think there is a problem with our topology? What would you recommend?
Do you think transforming to following topology would help?
-Building 2 hazelcast cluster node01-02 and node03-04, by monitoring these 2 clusters over Management Center
- Share traffic by LoadBalancer over 2 nodes node01-02 and route requests by DataPower to that virtual service.
- Share internal webservice requests to all nodes by LB through using cookie persistence.

Comment: `Sometimes, Hazelcast cluster works like 2 different clusters` do you know why ? Sounds like connectivity issues. Logs from the time might help.

Comment: "traffic is controlled by load balancer among them" --> Hazelcast members does not need a load balancer among them, neither a load balancer in front of your cluster is needed. By design, Hazelcast distributes your data equally to your members, and incoming requests are directed to the correct member where related data is stored. As Neil stated it sounds like you had a split brain and load balancer might be contributing to it.